# How to reset bootstrap modal to its original contents on close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

P.S I am not very good in javascript and I know this question has been asked but the solutions does not apply to my problem so I will ask this question again.

I'm stuck with this problem and haven't find the solution yet. I wanted to clear all the things that happened into my modal after its close.

My modal is a form modal, so whenever I click submit, codeigniter validation messages will show by the use of ajax on `<div style="font-size:10px;width:50%;" id="info"></div>` . Now whenever I close the modal, the validation messages stays when I re-open it. What should be done in order to clear those out after closing the modal?

This is the function called by the ajax:

```
public function addcomp () {
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->helper('security');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('comp_name','Computer Name','trim|required|callback_pc_exist');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('status','Status','trim|required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('location','Location','trim|required');

  if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

    $this->load->model('asset_model');
    $result=$this->asset_model->addpc();

    if (!$result) {
      echo mysqli_error($result);
    } else {
      echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
      Computer Successfully Added!</div>";
    }
  }
  echo validation_errors("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>","</div>");
}
```

This is the ajax called by submission:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addpc").submit(function(){
    var formdata=$("#addpc").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url:"asset_management/addcomp",
      type:"POST",
      data: formdata,
      async: true,
    }).done(function( formdata ) {
      $('#info').html(formdata);
      $("#addpc")[0].reset();
      viewdata();
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you add the validation messages? Any specific ones?

Comment: @PraveenKumar edited my post

Comment: Yes, checked. Kindly check my answer. Replace the `#info` with either `.alert-error` or whatever is the class needs to be removed.

Comment: Did the updated answer help you, buddy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the [Bootstrap's Modal Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events). You should be concerned about these two:

> - `hide.bs.modal` This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
> - `hidden.bs.modal`   This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

So, you can do this:

```
$(function () {
  // Delegating to `document` just in case.
  $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#myModalID", function () {
    $(this).find("#info").html(""); // Just clear the contents.
    $(this).find("#info").remove(); // Remove from DOM.
  });
});
```

**Update**

Seeing your code, you might need to use this:

```
$(function () {
  // Delegating to `document` just in case.
  $(document).on("hidden.bs.modal", "#myModalID", function () {
    $(this).find(".alert-danger").remove(); // Remove from DOM.
  });
});
```

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Ha ha ha. See OP's post: `$("#addpc")[0].reset();`.

Comment: Sorry Praveen.. I thought he would have that required field validations on each field and that he want to remove. So resetting the form would be better option right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao This looks like a server side, hard coded validations.

Comment: I would have lost reputation now if I would have answered.. :P

Comment: Yea.. Just read that he is keeping all those in a single `div` too.. Your solution should work... :)